# Calculation of an angle in tikz (fraction of light) including sin^-1

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I want to calculate the deviation angle \beta with the law of Snellius in a tikzpicture.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);} %voor pijltjes
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
\tkzInit[ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 10/1/D, 12/0.8/F};
\draw (O) circle(4cm);

\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](145:5){A}; 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](-120/3*2:5){B}; 
%\tkzDefShiftPoint[O]((3*5):5){C}; %% brackets don't work 

%circle
\foreach \x in {0,10,...,360} {\draw (\x:3.5cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\foreach \x in {5,15,...,355} {\draw (\x:3.7cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,359} {\draw (\x:3.9cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O)-- +(0:3cm) arc (0:-180:3cm) -- cycle;
%%% tekenen van de invalshoek
\draw (A)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (O) ;
\draw (O)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (B) ;

%%% tekenen van de assen
\draw[black] (-4.5cm,0cm) -- (4.5cm,0cm) ;
\draw[black] (0cm,-4.5cm) -- (0cm,4.5cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]

I see that there is a possibility to calculate some things in the definition of a point. See point B.

But my problems:

1) using brackets gives an error.

2) how to calculate a sin(a) or sin^-1(value) in the definition of that angle.

If I have a solution for this I want to create a macro that automatic calculates the deviation angle (and draws the beams) when the alfa is given an de deviation index. Using the formule: n=sin(alfa)/sin(beta)

Comment: Use `(3*5:5){B}`, no brackets needed. and `sin(15) will give you the value and `arcsin{1.5)` will do too.

Comment: @HarishKumar `asin` I think.

Comment: @HarishKumar indeed no brackets needed. I knew that (was just an example to reproduce the problem ;-) ) but I want to define the angle as -(90-(arcsin(a)/1,5)) since the angle in the formule gives me a positive result. But in physics i is the angle defined between the negative side of the y-axe and the beam and always positive. Drawing an angle in that part of the circle must be done with a negative argument. So I use this 'trick'.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. asin(0.3) or arcsin(0.4) gives the same error with the brackets. asin{0.4} does the job

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Argh. yea. made a typo.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've adapted the code, and managed to create the macro, except for a strange behavior of the calculated angle. Should I post this in "my answer" or adapt my own question?

Comment: Kind of up to you, you could post an answer here and then post a new question specifically about the calculated angle, or just edit your question to include the new example with the macro.

Comment: I seems that @HarishKumar was quicker... :-)

Comment: @Arne: Actually I was having my dinner :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sin(x)` to get the value and `asin(x)` to get `arcsin` value. The following works:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nindex}{1.3}      %% n
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incident}{30}     %% angle of incidence
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inci}{90+\incident}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\refracted}{270+asin(sin(\incident)/\nindex)}
```

so that you can use `\inci` and `\refracted` for the incident and `refracted` angles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);} %voor pijltjes
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nindex}{1.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incident}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inci}{90+\incident}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\refracted}{270+asin(sin(\incident)/\nindex)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
\tkzInit[ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 10/1/D, 12/0.8/F};
\draw (O) circle(4cm);

%circle
\foreach \x in {0,10,...,360} {\draw (\x:3.5cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\foreach \x in {5,15,...,355} {\draw (\x:3.7cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,359} {\draw (\x:3.9cm) -- (\x:4cm);}
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O)-- +(0:3cm) arc (0:-180:3cm) -- cycle;
%%% tekenen van de assen
\draw[black] (-4.5cm,0cm) -- (4.5cm,0cm) ;
\draw[black] (0cm,-4.5cm) -- (0cm,4.5cm) ;


\newcommand\lichtstraalbk[2]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nindex}{#1}      %% n
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incident}{#2}     %% angle of incidence
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inci}{90+\incident}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\refracted}{270+asin(sin(\incident)/\nindex)}

\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](\inci:5){A}; 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](\refracted:5){B}; %%% 
\draw (A)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (O) ; %drawing the incidence
\draw (O)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (B) ; 
}

\lichtstraalbk{1.5}{30}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I made it with a macro, can I adapt your answer?

Comment: @Arne Please, by all means.

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\Diagram#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m,arrowscale=3](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psframe*[linecolor=cyan!50](-6,0)(6,-6)
    \pscircle{5}
    \psline(-6,0)(6,0)
    \psline(0,-6)(0,6)
    \foreach \a in {0,10,...,350}{\psline(4.4;\a)(5;\a)}
    \foreach \a in {5,15,...,355}{\psline(4.6;\a)(5;\a)}
    \foreach \a in {1,2,...,359}{\psline(4.8;\a)(5;\a)}% kill unwanted whitespaces
    \pstVerb{/Angle #1 def /Index .75 def}
    \psset{ArrowInside=->}
    \psline(!6 Angle 90 add PtoC)(0,0)
    \psline(!6 Angle sin Index mul asin 270 add PtoC)
\end{pspicture}}


\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {10,20,...,80}{\Diagram{\Angle}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pstricks is not yet on my learning planning :-), but these one triggers my interest!